# Display posts subcategory from category (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

How edit this code, to display only subcategory (from single category) of single post. 
I started to write condition, that if this post has a category Berlin, then display all subcategories, that have been checked (alway it is one subcategory).
F.e. I would display "Potsdamer Platz(title)" Place:Berlin (category), Modern (subcategory of Berlin)

```
<?php 
if ( in_category( 'Berlin' )) {
```

Berlin    `//Parent Category`

-Mittelstadt    `// Subcategory`

-Altstadt     `// Subcategory`

-Modern `// Subcategory`

```
$subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=66&hide_empty=1'); 
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
  echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: What is it displaying now?

Comment: All subcategories from Berlin: Mittelstadt, Altstadt, Modern

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried out your code and it works perfectly:

```
<?php 
if ( in_category( 'Blog' )) {

$subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=2&hide_empty=1'); 
echo '<ul class="categories">';
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
  echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
}
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Screenshot of categories in dashboard:
[image]

Screenshot of post page with subcategory link at top:
[image]

As you can see it's adding the subcategory link of what the post is in. I don't know if you want to loop through your posts and display `[title][main-category][subcategory]`?

Let me know if you want to loop through your posts and display it like this `[title][main-category][subcategory]` and I'll show you how.

Comment: Thank You for You support. Yes, that's how works my code, but I need to display only this subcategory which the post has, not all. Yes, this is in loop in category.php

Comment: Then just add your code into your theme single.php file which is what wordpress uses when displaying single posts. It will display the subcategory of that specific post wherever you add your code.

Comment: Thank You. But it will not appear in category.php view (when I display content of single category), or am I wrong?

Comment: Send a screenshot or link of what you want so I can understand better and give correct answer :)